# Gunicorn/Flask reject identical SSL certificate that works fine with Apache

Tags: ssl, apache2, gunicorn, flask, ssl-certificate-errors

What would cause a Gunicorn server running a Flask app to report a "sslv3 alert certificate unknown" error in the browser, when an Apache server running a WSGI app, using the exact same certificate on the exact same machine, reports no problems?

The Gunicorn service is hosting from the domain https://mysub.example.com:1234 while the Apache service hosts from the standard port 80 at https://mysub.example.com.

Both services are hosted on the same physical server, and load the wildcard SSL certificate located at `/etc/ssl/certs`.

The logs from Gunicorn/Flask aren't providing much feedback and are simply showing:

```
[2021-06-23 12:55:34 -0500] [2320785] [DEBUG] Error processing SSL request.
[2021-06-23 12:55:34 -0500] [2320785] [DEBUG] Invalid request from ip=123.45.678.90: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:2633)
```

The Gunicorn server is run via Supervisor with as user `www-data` the command:

```
/usr/local/alphabuyer/.env/bin/gunicorn --certfile=/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt --keyfile=/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.key --bind 0.0.0.0:1234 server:app
```

Meanwhile, the SSL settings for Apache config are:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.intermediate.crt
SSLProtocol all
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
```

I've checked the permissions in `/etc/ssl/certs`, and they appear to be correct. Everything's owned by user `www-data` chmoded to 600.

I don't see any reason why the certificate would be served correctly by Apache but not by Gunicorn. The error message suggests it's not necessarily anything Gunicorn is serving, but an error or some supported feature with the request the browser is making. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn (and virtually everything else that does TLS *except* Apache) expects your TLS certificate to be concatenated with the intermediate certificates in a single file.

Create the concatenated file:

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.intermediate.crt > /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.chain.crt
```

Now use it in your command line.

```
.... --certfile=/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.chain.crt ....
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/639837/openssl-s-client-shows-alert-certificate-unknown-but-all-server-certificates-app), and the underlying cause was that my client certificates were out of date.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/761183) solved my problem, by updating my local `ca-certificates` package.